# Replay on BG Music

Tags: java, android

I made a service that play background music, but when the music finished I want to replay it again. Which method can I use in my service?

```
public class BackgroundSoundService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = null;
    MediaPlayer player;
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();


        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.idil);

        player.setVolume(100,100);

    }
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


        player.start();

        return 1;
    }

    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        // TODO



    }
    public IBinder onUnBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return null;
    }

    public void onStop() {

    }
    public void onPause() {

    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        player.stop();
        player.release();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use [`MediaPlayer.setLooping()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setLooping%28boolean%29) method.

Sample code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.idil);
    player.setVolume(100,100);
    player.setLooping(true);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set [OnCompletionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html) via [setOnCompletionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnCompletionListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener%29). And it he callback you can start it again.